# MongoDB query check if value in array property

Tags: mongodb, querying

I cannot find out of how to check, if some value are in array property in mongo document.
For example, I have some collection users, and such document:

```js
{
  'name':'Paul',
  'age':43,
  'friendsIDs': [ ObjectId('qqq...'), ObjectId('www...'), ObjectId('eee...') ],
}
```

Now let's suppose that I want to check, is user with ID ObjectId('qqq...') a friend of Paul, or not.
This is quite easy to do in almost all programming languages, for example in php it would be something like:

```js
$isFriendOfPaul = in_array( ObjectId('qqq...'), $friendsIds );
```

But how to query this in mongo? Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually, it is **$in** the [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/).

Comment: show me the query please.
It's vice versa of query with $in.

Comment: "If the field holds an array, then the $in operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains at least one element that matches a value in the specified array (e.g. <value1>, <value2>, etc.)" -- so it should work both ways. So I guess you could try to get it: `db.collection.find({friendsIDs: {$in: [YourIDValue]}})`

Comment: Nobody even addresses the pun that made me fall over?

Comment: *badumts tching* 

Answer (score 3):

Your query must be like this:

```
db.collection.find({"name": "Paul", "friendsIDs": "qqq"})
```

This query finds the document with name `Paul` and `friendsIDs` equal to `qqq`.

Comment: 'friendsIDs' is a list (array) of Ids, not one ID

Comment: This works fine even when `friendsIDs` is an array.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#array-element-equals-a-value

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with [$eq](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/)

```
> db.person.insert({name: 'Paul', age: 43, friends: [1234, 2345, 3456]})
> db.person.insert({name: 'Dave', age: 23, friends: [2345, 3456]})
> db.person.insert({name: 'Stephen', age: 12, friends: [2345, 3456, 7890]})
```

Below is an example using $eq:

```
> db.person.find({friends: {$eq : 2345}}) 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54e34124fe135475834334da"), "name" : "Paul", "age" : 43, "friends" : [ 1234, 2345, 3456 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54e34138fe135475834334db"), "name" : "Dave", "age" : 23, "friends" : [ 2345, 3456 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54e3414bfe135475834334dc"), "name" : "Stephen", "age" : 12, "friends" : [ 2345, 3456, 7890 ] }
```

but the queries below also find the same. So as Sven suggested, you can leave out $eq.

```
> db.person.find({friends: 2345})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54e34124fe135475834334da"), "name" : "Paul", "age" : 43, "friends" : [ 1234, 2345, 3456 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54e34138fe135475834334db"), "name" : "Dave", "age" : 23, "friends" : [ 2345, 3456 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54e3414bfe135475834334dc"), "name" : "Stephen", "age" : 12, "friends" : [ 2345, 3456, 7890 ] }

> db.person.find({friends: 1234})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54e34124fe135475834334da"), "name" : "Paul", "age" : 43, "friends" : [ 1234, 2345, 3456 ] }
```